# How can you restart on a specific line in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner and I tried to create a simple calculator in c#. I want that, when you finish an operation, you can restart or not. 
Heres my code:

```
    using System;

namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // First number
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
                double A = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            // Second number
            Console.WriteLine("Enter another number");
                double B = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            // Operator
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the operator");
                string C = Console.ReadLine();
                    // if you want to add
                    if(C == "+")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(A + B);
                    }
                    // if you want to remove
                    if(C == "-")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(A - B);
                    }
                    // if you want to multiply
                    if(C == "*")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(A * B);
                    }
                    // if you want to subdivide
                    if(C == "/")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(A / B);
                    }
            // Ask if they want to restart or finish
            Console.WriteLine("Want to do another operations? y/n");
                string W = Console.ReadLine();
                    // Restart
                    if(W == "y")
                    {
                        // Return at the beginning
                    }
                    // Finish
                    if(W == "n")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter a key to close"); 
                            Console.ReadKey();
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can see which, when you finish your operation, you can restart(Which is the one I don't understand how) or finish.
My code (and my speech) are not efficient (I'm Italian)
I'm bad at programming, I'm trying to learn by myself.

Comment: Put it all in a loop, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/branches-and-loops?tutorial-step=3

Comment: Check out the [while](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while) loop.

Comment: I agree. a while loop seems pretty good here to use.

Answer (score 2):

The concrete answer to your question, how to jump to a concrete line is: `goto`
You place a label `myLabel:` and then when you want to jump there you do `goto myLabel;`

BUT, goto is evil, it must be avoided, in a large program it makes code unreadable and leads to a ton of problems.

The good solution would be to create a loop and test for a variable, something like this:

```
bool execute = true;

while(execute)
{

    //..your calculator code

    Console.WriteLine("Want to do another operations? y/n");
    string W = Console.ReadLine();

    if(W == "n")
        execute = false;

}
```

This makes the code a lot more clean and readable.